How to companion app wear and phone? When building application ID vs signingConfigs
To automatically install Wear OS apps when you install apps on your phone, you can follow Google's instructions on distributing Wear OS apps. Currently I have not found a way, to deploy to the store, I have to go to chplay on wear to install my own application.
I have tried researching many ways but have not seen any document mentioned.

This question is similar to: How to install WearOS companion app along with the Android phone app automatically. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Currently wear os 3.0 and above behavior is different, there are many different ways to configure, the old way 2.0 config multiple apk, I really think this question is necessary for wear 3.0 and above. I have researched quite a lot. Haven't found a solution yet.

Your question is quite confusing. You can make the wear app require the mobile app using by setting it to non-standalone, although I think you want it the other way around.
